# MySQL Killed by OOM after Corrupted Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, corruption

One of our web-app servers recently had an issue where MySQL was taking more memory than we have physical RAM.  This server has 64GB of memory and 8GB in swap, and MySQL was OOM-ed because it was using over 69GB of memory.

After the fact I found logs indicating that one of our database tables had become corrupted several hours before the issue occurred, and there are literally millions of log entries in the three hours before the OOM complaining about this table being corrupt.

I want to understand why this happened so that I can prevent it.  Here are the relevant portions of my MySQL configuration:

```
max_connections = 1000
table_open_cache = 1000
query_cache_size = 1G

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16GB
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 24M
```

I've also read these similar questions:

- [MySQL crashing randomly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72053/mysql-crashing-randomly)
- [Linux 32b MySQL periodically crashing with signal 11 and OOM errors](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37398/linux-32b-mysql-periodically-crashing-with-signal-11-and-oom-errors)

I don't believe the answers to those questions apply (I checked the variables they mention), and I don't see how MySQL could reasonably use ~49GB of memory for 1000 connections.  However, there were a lot of connections open at the time of the crash, and I noticed afterward that an `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` query against the corrupted table (which was MyISAM) was hanging indefinitely.

Does anyone know why MySQL would have consumed so much memory so suddenly (MySQL usually uses ~24GB of memory on this server)?  Was the corrupted table related, or was this caused by a misconfiguration?

Note: I have completed a memory test on this server without errors.

---

Show variables:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+---
| Variable_name                                     | Value
+---------------------------------------------------+---
| auto_increment_increment                          | 1
| auto_increment_offset                             | 1
| autocommit                                        | ON
| automatic_sp_privileges                           | ON
| back_log                                          | 50
| big_tables                                        | OFF
| binlog_cache_size                                 | 32768
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates           | OFF
| binlog_format                                     | MIXED
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                            | 32768
| bulk_insert_buffer_size                           | 8388608
| completion_type                                   | NO_CHAIN
| concurrent_insert                                 | AUTO
| connect_timeout                                   | 10
| default_storage_engine                            | InnoDB
| delay_key_write                                   | ON
| delayed_insert_limit                              | 100
| delayed_insert_timeout                            | 300
| delayed_queue_size                                | 1000
| div_precision_increment                           | 4
| engine_condition_pushdown                         | ON
| error_count                                       | 0
| event_scheduler                                   | OFF
| foreign_key_checks                                | ON
| group_concat_max_len                              | 1024
| ignore_builtin_innodb                             | OFF
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                          | ON
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index                        | ON
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size                   | 8388608
| innodb_autoextend_increment                       | 8
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                          | 1
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances                      | 4
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                           | 17179869184
| innodb_change_buffering                           | all
| innodb_checksums                                  | ON
| innodb_commit_concurrency                         | 0
| innodb_concurrency_tickets                        | 500
| innodb_data_file_path                             | ibdata1:10M:autoextend
| innodb_doublewrite                                | ON
| innodb_fast_shutdown                              | 1
| innodb_file_format                                | Antelope
| innodb_file_format_check                          | ON
| innodb_file_format_max                            | Antelope
| innodb_file_per_table                             | ON
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit                    | 0
| innodb_flush_method                               | O_DIRECT
| innodb_force_load_corrupted                       | OFF
| innodb_force_recovery                             | 0
| innodb_io_capacity                                | 200
| innodb_large_prefix                               | OFF
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                          | 50
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog                    | OFF
| innodb_log_buffer_size                            | 25165824
| innodb_log_file_size                              | 1073741824
| innodb_log_files_in_group                         | 2
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                        | 75
| innodb_max_purge_lag                              | 0
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups                        | 1
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                             | 37
| innodb_old_blocks_time                            | 0
| innodb_open_files                                 | 300
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks                        | OFF
| innodb_purge_batch_size                           | 20
| innodb_purge_threads                              | 0
| innodb_random_read_ahead                          | OFF
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold                       | 56
| innodb_read_io_threads                            | 4
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                        | OFF
| innodb_rollback_segments                          | 128
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                            | 6
| innodb_stats_method                               | nulls_equal
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                          | ON
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                         | 8
| innodb_strict_mode                                | OFF
| innodb_support_xa                                 | ON
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                            | 30
| innodb_table_locks                                | ON
| innodb_thread_concurrency                         | 0
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                         | 10000
| innodb_use_native_aio                             | ON
| innodb_use_sys_malloc                             | ON
| innodb_version                                    | 5.5.44
| innodb_write_io_threads                           | 4
| interactive_timeout                               | 28800
| join_buffer_size                                  | 131072
| keep_files_on_create                              | OFF
| key_buffer_size                                   | 67108864
| key_cache_age_threshold                           | 300
| key_cache_block_size                              | 1024
| key_cache_division_limit                          | 100
| large_files_support                               | ON
| large_page_size                                   | 0
| large_pages                                       | OFF
| local_infile                                      | ON
| lock_wait_timeout                                 | 31536000
| locked_in_memory                                  | OFF
| low_priority_updates                              | OFF
| max_allowed_packet                                | 134217728
| max_binlog_size                                   | 104857600
| max_connect_errors                                | 10
| max_connections                                   | 1000
| max_delayed_threads                               | 20
| max_error_count                                   | 64
| max_heap_table_size                               | 16777216
| max_insert_delayed_threads                        | 20
| max_length_for_sort_data                          | 1024
| max_long_data_size                                | 134217728
| max_prepared_stmt_count                           | 16382
| max_relay_log_size                                | 0
| max_sort_length                                   | 1024
| max_sp_recursion_depth                            | 0
| max_tmp_tables                                    | 32
| max_user_connections                              | 0
| metadata_locks_cache_size                         | 1024
| min_examined_row_limit                            | 0
| multi_range_count                                 | 256
| myisam_data_pointer_size                          | 6
| myisam_recover_options                            | BACKUP
| myisam_repair_threads                             | 1
| myisam_sort_buffer_size                           | 8388608
| myisam_stats_method                               | nulls_unequal
| myisam_use_mmap                                   | OFF
| net_buffer_length                                 | 16384
| net_read_timeout                                  | 30
| net_retry_count                                   | 10
| net_write_timeout                                 | 60
| open_files_limit                                  | 65500
| optimizer_prune_level                             | 1
| optimizer_search_depth                            | 62
| preload_buffer_size                               | 32768
| protocol_version                                  | 10
| query_alloc_block_size                            | 8192
| query_cache_limit                                 | 1048576
| query_cache_min_res_unit                          | 4096
| query_cache_size                                  | 1073741824
| query_cache_type                                  | ON
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate                      | OFF
| query_prealloc_size                               | 8192
| range_alloc_block_size                            | 4096
| read_buffer_size                                  | 131072
| read_only                                         | OFF
| read_rnd_buffer_size                              | 262144
| rpl_recovery_rank                                 | 0
| skip_external_locking                             | ON
| sort_buffer_size                                  | 2097152
| sql_big_selects                                   | ON
| sql_big_tables                                    | OFF
| sql_buffer_result                                 | OFF
| storage_engine                                    | InnoDB
| stored_program_cache                              | 256
| sync_binlog                                       | 0
| sync_frm                                          | ON
| sync_master_info                                  | 0
| sync_relay_log                                    | 0
| sync_relay_log_info                               | 0
| table_definition_cache                            | 400
| table_open_cache                                  | 1000
| thread_cache_size                                 | 8
| thread_concurrency                                | 10
| thread_handling                                   | one-thread-per-connection
| thread_stack                                      | 196608
| time_zone                                         | SYSTEM
| timed_mutexes                                     | OFF
| tmp_table_size                                    | 16777216
| transaction_alloc_block_size                      | 8192
| transaction_prealloc_size                         | 4096
| tx_isolation                                      | REPEATABLE-READ
| unique_checks                                     | ON
| updatable_views_with_limit                        | YES
| wait_timeout                                      | 28800
| warning_count                                     | 0
+---------------------------------------------------+--
```

Show Global Status:

```
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value         |
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Aborted_clients                          | 9             |
| Aborted_connects                         | 5201          |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use                    | 566           |
| Binlog_cache_use                         | 59455472      |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use               | 170           |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use                    | 7980756       |
| Bytes_received                           | 118197326576  |
| Bytes_sent                               | 936083868833  |
| Connections                              | 15785450      |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables                  | 37787519      |
| Created_tmp_files                        | 1385          |
| Created_tmp_tables                       | 70916100      |
| Delayed_errors                           | 0             |
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0             |
| Delayed_writes                           | 0             |
| Flush_commands                           | 78            |
| Handler_commit                           | 306649532     |
| Handler_delete                           | 232632        |
| Handler_discover                         | 0             |
| Handler_prepare                          | 93231428      |
| Handler_read_first                       | 60815625      |
| Handler_read_key                         | 885609313     |
| Handler_read_last                        | 838614        |
| Handler_read_next                        | 4197678356    |
| Handler_read_prev                        | 357472833     |
| Handler_read_rnd                         | 101193542     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next                    | 52819751104   |
| Handler_rollback                         | 28462         |
| Handler_savepoint                        | 0             |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback               | 0             |
| Handler_update                           | 64446304      |
| Handler_write                            | 412627899     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data            | 1048088       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data            | 17171873792   |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty           | 431           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty           | 7061504       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed         | 43659545      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free            | 2             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc            | 482           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total           | 1048572       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd        | 0             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead            | 848473        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted    | 358935        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests         | 23851889088   |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                 | 132872602     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free             | 0             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests        | 454509933     |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                       | 14157861      |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs               | 0             |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                | 0             |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes               | 0             |
| Innodb_data_read                         | 2191680999424 |
| Innodb_data_reads                        | 134331079     |
| Innodb_data_writes                       | 49646417      |
| Innodb_data_written                      | 1460362066432 |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written               | 43659545      |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                      | 1967389       |
| Innodb_have_atomic_builtins              | ON            |
| Innodb_log_waits                         | 0             |
| Innodb_log_write_requests                | 55918265      |
| Innodb_log_writes                        | 2817833       |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                     | 3218361       |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs             | 0             |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes             | 0             |
| Innodb_os_log_written                    | 29521291776   |
| Innodb_page_size                         | 16384         |
| Innodb_pages_created                     | 1082758       |
| Innodb_pages_read                        | 133769705     |
| Innodb_pages_written                     | 43659545      |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits            | 0             |
| Innodb_row_lock_time                     | 441363        |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg                 | 1219          |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max                 | 51820         |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                    | 362           |
| Innodb_rows_deleted                      | 210683        |
| Innodb_rows_inserted                     | 6673020       |
| Innodb_rows_read                         | 55723159186   |
| Innodb_rows_updated                      | 61534004      |
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes           | 0             |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed                   | 0             |
| Key_blocks_unused                        | 50984         |
| Key_blocks_used                          | 53585         |
| Key_read_requests                        | 1649235730    |
| Key_reads                                | 90119161      |
| Key_write_requests                       | 4078153       |
| Key_writes                               | 2287803       |
| Last_query_cost                          | 0.000000      |
| Max_used_connections                     | 219           |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows                 | 0             |
| Open_files                               | 842           |
| Open_streams                             | 0             |
| Open_table_definitions                   | 921           |
| Open_tables                              | 1000          |
| Opened_files                             | 504435699     |
| Opened_table_definitions                 | 115393300     |
| Opened_tables                            | 112827119     |
| Prepared_stmt_count                      | 0             |
| Qcache_free_blocks                       | 58397         |
| Qcache_free_memory                       | 377606768     |
| Qcache_hits                              | 600978542     |
| Qcache_inserts                           | 160064226     |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes                     | 17296550      |
| Qcache_not_cached                        | 66882759      |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache                  | 471854        |
| Qcache_total_blocks                      | 1013507       |
| Queries                                  | 1204594580    |
| Questions                                | 1201397855    |
| Rpl_status                               | AUTH_MASTER   |
| Select_full_join                         | 152194        |
| Select_full_range_join                   | 0             |
| Select_range                             | 9798991       |
| Select_range_check                       | 0             |
| Select_scan                              | 116607434     |
| Slave_heartbeat_period                   | 30.000        |
| Slave_open_temp_tables                   | 0             |
| Slave_received_heartbeats                | 2559          |
| Slave_retried_transactions               | 0             |
| Slave_running                            | OFF           |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0             |
| Slow_queries                             | 3255          |
| Sort_merge_passes                        | 3             |
| Sort_range                               | 14976751      |
| Sort_rows                                | 144820896     |
| Sort_scan                                | 11605905      |
| Table_locks_immediate                    | 380794869     |
| Table_locks_waited                       | 105           |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used                    | 0             |
| Tc_log_page_size                         | 0             |
| Tc_log_page_waits                        | 0             |
| Threads_cached                           | 7             |
| Threads_connected                        | 3             |
| Threads_created                          | 2873          |
| Threads_running                          | 3             |
| Uptime                                   | 4892974       |
| Uptime_since_flush_status                | 4892974       |
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Not enough.  version is missing.  Uptime is missing, so the counters are useless -- can't get "per second".  (May need to use some postit site because of the length.)

Comment: I've updated the Global Status section with uptime, etc.  Version is 5.5.44.

Comment: Sorry, to do a thorough analysis, I need all of both the `VARIABLES` and `STATUS`.

Comment: I've put all of `STATUS`, but all of `VARIABLES` certainly won't fit.  However, I've tried to only take out things like file paths, counter limit sizes (almost all of which are `LONG_MAX` or `ULONG_MAX`), character sets, etc. Is there anything specific you need that is missing?

Answer (score 1):

`query_cache_size = 1G` -- This is really bad.  Don't set it bigger than about 50M.  It won't directly cause a crash, but it can cause lengthy stalls, which could lead to a crash.

When *any* write occurs to a table, *all* entries in the QC for that table is purged.  The bigger the QC the longer that takes.

The QC is "in front of" the engines (MyISAM and InnoDB).  That is, first the QC is checked to see if the *exact* query is still there, in which case the resultset is returned.  Otherwise, the engine takes over and does a different level of caching (key_buffer + OS space for MyISAM; buffer_pool for InnoDB).

`max_connections = 1000` -- What "client" do you have?  Can it really produce that many connections?

A likely causes  `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` should not be bigger than, say, 1% of RAM.  Else you are at a big risk of running out of RAM when a lot of connections perform complex queries.

MyISAM's indexes become corrupted whenever there is an ungraceful shutdown.  This is a strong reason to switch to InnoDB.

Did you raise `key_buffer_size`?  It should not be bigger than about 20% of RAM.

Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`; I will check to see what else might be over-sized.

Comment: No, I've never seen that many simultaneous connections, but I was maxing out with the default of 150. I did not raise `tmp_table_size` or `max_heap_table_size`. `key_buffer_size` is slightly bigger, but nowhere near 20% RAM. See my edited answer for variables and status.

Comment: Also, could you help me understand why a large `query_cache_size` would cause lengthy stalls? I thought that the query cache was to some degree for MyISAM what the buffer pool is for InnoDB.

Comment: add a couple of paragraphs about the QC

Comment: `table_open_cache` may be too low, based on the very high `Opened_tables`.  (Can't tell for sure without `Uptime`.)